# Magento invoice grid filter_condition_callback not working

Tags: magento, filter, grid

I added a custom column to invoice grid using an observer.
The problem is that I can't sort or filter by the new column.

I added a filter condition callback but the function is not called.

Here is my Observer.php

```
class DB_CustomGrid_Model_Adminhtml_Observer
{
    public function onBlockHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();

        $payment_methods = array();
        $readConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $query = 'SELECT method FROM '.Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_payment').' GROUP BY method';
        $methods = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
        foreach($methods as $payment) {
            if($payment["method"] !== 'free') {
                $payment_methods[$payment["method"]] = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$payment["method"].'/title');
            }
        }

        switch ($block->getType()) {
            case 'adminhtml/sales_invoice_grid':
                $block->addColumnAfter('state', array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
                    'index' => 'method',
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'width' => '70px',
                    'options' => $payment_methods,
                    'filter' => false,
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_myCustomFilter'),
                ), 'method');
            break;
        }
    }

    public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderInvoiceGridCollection();
        $collection->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.order_id=parent_id',array('method'));
    }

    protected function _myCustomFilter($collection, $column)
    {
        exit;
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $collection;
        }

        $collection->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("sales_order_payment.method like ?", "%$value%");
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

I added an exit; to check if the function is called or not.

Comment: Try rewriting adminhtml/sales_invoice_grid, add column and filter in Your grid.

Comment: I think $this in 'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_myCustomFilter') indicates observer not grid.

Comment: I don't want to rewrite the core files. That's why I use the observer method.
Can I access the grid object there? But I think the function should be called whatever the first parameter is`?

Comment: so try passing $block instead $this

Comment: I this there is no $collection in _myCustomFilter

Comment: I tried this: 'filter_condition_callback' => array($observer->getOrderInvoiceGridCollection(), '_myCustomFilter'),

But the callback function is still not called.

Comment: Did you get anything working on this?

Comment: After some testing, it looks like Observer callbacks need to be declared as `public` to function.

Comment: Declaring as public is the solution? (we already have this and it was and is not working still)

Comment: FYI https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/magento-grid-filter-condition-callback-ignored-in-magento-ver-1-9-4-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add a new protected function to your observer class:

```
protected function _callProtectedMethod($object, $methodName) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($object);
    $method = $reflection->getMethod($methodName);
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    return $method->invoke($object);
}
```

Then call `$block->sortColumnsByOrder()` and the new function `$this->_callProtectedMethod($block, '_prepareCollection')` directly after `$block->addColumnAfter();`

Comment: This does work, but why is this necessary?  What is wrong with OP's logic?

Comment: Was this marked as the solution?? And why ... trying to understand what is wrong here ... because in Magento 1.9.2. this worked fine and after 1.9.3. not anymore

Comment: Tries this solution, now see `Method _prepareCollection does not exist`